# deserialize various objects in netty

Tags: java, netty

I am using standard *ObjectDecoder* and *ObjectEncoder* from netty framework.

1. Is it safe to serialized, deserialize objects of various types via only one instance of concrete *ObjectDecoder*, *ObjectDecoder*?
2. Why the default *ObjectDecoder* constructor is depracated?
3. Suitable version of constructor has got *ClassReslover* as a argument.
   Does *ClassResolver* constructor imply that only one type of objects can be de/serialized by these concrete (*ObjectDecoder*, *ObjectEncoder*) objects and to de/serialize another i have to switch these(*ObjectDecoder*, *ObjectDecoder*) Objects in *ChannelPipeline*?

I am writing server which should response on various type of request and i wanna implement by this way.

May be one standard message class with TYPE_REQUEST field will be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it safe to serialized, deserialize objects of various types via only one instance of concrete ObjectDecoder, ObjectDecoder?

Yes. The ObjectDecoder doesn't generally have state (other than the class loader, which likely won't change) - it creates anything else it needs when you call decode(). The classloader is also optional - you can pass null and it'll use whatever class loader (in my case the default one) is in context when you go to decode.

> Why the default ObjectDecoder constructor is depracated?

I'm not sure about this. I'm using Netty 3.2.4 and it's not deprecated. Version info is:
 * @version $Rev: 2279 $, $Date: 2010-05-13 23:13:07 +0900 (Thu, 13 May 2010) $

If you're using a more recent version, look in the javadoc, it should tell you.

> Suitable version of constructor has got ClassReslover as a argument. Does ClassResolver constructor imply that only one type of
>   objects can be de/serialized by these concrete (ObjectDecoder,
>   ObjectEncoder) objects and to de/serialize another i have to switch
>   these(ObjectDecoder, ObjectDecoder) Objects in ChannelPipeline?

Not at all. The ClassLoader arg is if you have some custom classloader that is needed because the default one is inadequate. You can serialize/deserialize anything with one ObjectDecoder, as long as you use the appropriate ObjectEncoder on the other side.

Comment: Thank you for all. There is nothing in netty-3.2.7 javadoc about why default ObjectDecoder constructor is depracated, but it isn't vital anymore.